# Cant Save relational Entities in breezejs

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework-6, breeze, webapp2

I have two entities created through `manager.createEntity(type);`.. *z-validate wont display validation errors if i try to create them otherwise* 
..entity **orderdetails** must have a valid key from **order**. and later...

```
...  //changed some stuff but never keys
orderdetails.Time = new Date();    
orderdetails.order = order;          //am i creating the relation right here?
```

The app will work great offline but when i save changes to the server..

```
manager.saveChanges([order,orderdetails]);
```

The sever is returning

```
...orderdetails","KeyValues":["fd...28"],"PropertyName":"order",ErrorMessage":"The order field is required."
```

Any idea how i can go through this? i have been reading documentations for days.

Metadata looks like this

```
{
    "schema": {
        "namespace": "Inventory.API",
        "alias": "Self",
        "annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes": "false",
        "xmlns:annotation": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation",
        "xmlns:customannotation": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation",
        "xmlns": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm",
        "cSpaceOSpaceMapping": "[\"Inventory.API.Order\",\"Inventory.API.Entities.Order\"],[\"Inventory.API.OrderDetail\",\"Inventory.API.Entities.OrderDetail\"],[\"Inventory.API.DifferentDetail\",\"Inventory.API.Entities.DifferentDetail\"]",
        "entityType": [ {
            "name": "Order",
            "customannotation:ClrType": "Inventory.API.Entities.Order, Inventory.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "key": {
                "propertyRef": {
                    "name": "Id"
                }
            },
            "property": [{
                "name": "Id",
                "type": "Edm.Guid",
                "nullable": "false",
                "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
            }, {
                "name": "BarCode",
                "type": "Edm.String",
                "maxLength": "Max",
                "fixedLength": "false",
                "unicode": "true"
            }, {
                "name": "Name",
                "type": "Edm.String",
                "maxLength": "Max",
                "fixedLength": "false",
                "unicode": "true"
            }, {
                "name": "UnitPrice",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "Count",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }],
            "navigationProperty": [{
                "name": "OrderDetails",
                "relationship": "Self.OrderDetail_Order",
                "fromRole": "OrderDetail_Order_Target",
                "toRole": "OrderDetail_Order_Source"
            }, {
                "name": "DifferentDetails",
                "relationship": "Self.DifferentDetail_Order",
                "fromRole": "DifferentDetail_Order_Target",
                "toRole": "DifferentDetail_Order_Source"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "OrderDetail",
            "customannotation:ClrType": "Inventory.API.Entities.OrderDetail, Inventory.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "key": {
                "propertyRef": {
                    "name": "Id"
                }
            },
            "property": [{
                "name": "Id",
                "type": "Edm.Guid",
                "nullable": "false",
                "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
            }, {
                "name": "Time",
                "type": "Edm.DateTime",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "UnitPrice",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "Count",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "TotalPrice",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }],
            "navigationProperty": {
                "name": "Order",
                "relationship": "Self.OrderDetail_Order",
                "fromRole": "OrderDetail_Order_Source",
                "toRole": "OrderDetail_Order_Target"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "DifferentDetail",
            "customannotation:ClrType": "Inventory.API.Entities.DifferentDetail, Inventory.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "key": {
                "propertyRef": {
                    "name": "Id"
                }
            },
            "property": [{
                "name": "Id",
                "type": "Edm.Guid",
                "nullable": "false",
                "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
            }, {
                "name": "Time",
                "type": "Edm.DateTime",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "UnitPrice",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "Count",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }, {
                "name": "TotalPrice",
                "type": "Edm.Decimal",
                "precision": "18",
                "scale": "2",
                "nullable": "false"
            }],
            "navigationProperty": {
                "name": "Order",
                "relationship": "Self.DifferentDetail_Order",
                "fromRole": "DifferentDetail_Order_Source",
                "toRole": "DifferentDetail_Order_Target"
            }
        }],
        "entityContainer": {
            "name": "InventoryContext",
            "customannotation:UseClrTypes": "true",
            "entitySet": [{
                "name": "Orders",
                "entityType": "Self.Order"
            }, {
                "name": "OrderDetails",
                "entityType": "Self.OrderDetail"
            }, {
                "name": "DifferentDetails",
                "entityType": "Self.DifferentDetail"
            }],
            "associationSet": [{
                "name": "OrderDetail_Order",
                "association": "Self.OrderDetail_Order",
                "end": [{
                    "role": "OrderDetail_Order_Source",
                    "entitySet": "OrderDetails"
                }, {
                    "role": "OrderDetail_Order_Target",
                    "entitySet": "Orders"
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "DifferentDetail_Order",
                "association": "Self.DifferentDetail_Order",
                "end": [{
                    "role": "DifferentDetail_Order_Source",
                    "entitySet": "DifferentDetails"
                }, {
                    "role": "DifferentDetail_Order_Target",
                    "entitySet": "Orders"
                }]
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your metadata look like for order and orderdetails?

Comment: @SteveSchmitt I think the Metadata was too huge for the comment section so i have updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the `orderId` foreign key property of the `OrderDetail` and `DifferentDetail` entities.  When Breeze sends the entities to the server, it communicates the relationship between entities using the foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks that worked.. couldn't find a way to add what i actually did it so i added an answer @steve

Answer (score 0):

I needed to map the orderId foreign key property of the OrderDetail and DifferentDetail entities. When Breeze sends the entities to the server, it communicates the relationship between entities using the foreign keys.

... The relation was there but breeze wont see it as it was defined like this

```
 [Required]
public Order Order { get; set; }
```

And therefore I changed it to this

```
 [Required]
public Guid Order_Id { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Order_Id")]
public virtual Order Order{get; set;}
```

in the DBContext POCO classes then created a new copy of Metadata.